# JS/React: Replace ids by values from constant

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'll be glad for any hint!
I have an array:

```
"languages": [
    {
        "languageId": 1,
        "languageLevelId": 2
    },
    {
        "languageId": 9,
        "languageLevelId": 3
    },
    {
        "languageId": 0,
        "languageLevelId": 3
    }
]
```

And constants:

```
export const LANGUAGE = {
    UKRAINIAN: 0,
    ENGLISH: 1,
    CHINESE: 2,
    SPANISH: 3,
    ARABIC: 4,
    JAPANESE: 5,
    HINDUSTANI: 6,
    FRENCH: 7,
    GERMAN: 8,
    RUSSIAN: 9,
    PORTUGUESE: 10,
    ITALIAN: 11
};

export const LANGUAGE_LEVEL = {
    BEGINNER: 0,
    INTERMEDIATE: 1,
    ADVANCED: 2,
    NATIVE: 3
};
```

How can I get something, like:

```
"languages": [
    {
        "languageId": ENGLISH,
        "languageLevelId": ADVANCED
    },
    ...
]
```

And then map languages, or what should I do in order to get such a result and get:
And then map languages, or what should I do in order to get such a result and get:

```
<div>English</div>
<div>Advanced</div>
```

Comment: I apologize for the duplication of text in the last paragraph.

Comment: This seems more like a logical issue you have to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I made a function that flips the key and the value of your object

```
function objectFlip(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((ret, key) => {
    ret[obj[key]] = key;
    return ret;
  }, {});
}
```

Then I just simply map the value to the languageId and languageLevelId

```js
const languages = [
    {
        "languageId": 1,
        "languageLevelId": 2
    },
    {
        "languageId": 9,
        "languageLevelId": 3
    },
    {
        "languageId": 0,
        "languageLevelId": 3
    }
]

const LANGUAGE = {
    UKRAINIAN: 0,
    ENGLISH: 1,
    CHINESE: 2,
    SPANISH: 3,
    ARABIC: 4,
    JAPANESE: 5,
    HINDUSTANI: 6,
    FRENCH: 7,
    GERMAN: 8,
    RUSSIAN: 9,
    PORTUGUESE: 10,
    ITALIAN: 11
};

const LANGUAGE_LEVEL = {
    BEGINNER: 0,
    INTERMEDIATE: 1,
    ADVANCED: 2,
    NATIVE: 3
};

function objectFlip(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((ret, key) => {
    ret[obj[key]] = key;
    return ret;
  }, {});
}

const invertedLanguage = objectFlip(LANGUAGE) // { 0: 'UKRANIAN', 1: 'ENGLISH', ...} 
const invertedLanguageLevel = objectFlip(LANGUAGE_LEVEL) // { 0: 'BEGINNER', 1: 'INTERMEDIATE', ... }


const updatedLanguage = languages.map(language => {
    language.languageId = invertedLanguage[language.languageId]
  language.languageLevelId = invertedLanguageLevel[language.languageLevelId]
  return language
})

console.log(updatedLanguage)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop both arrays to get the correct values

```js
let languages = [
    {
        "languageId": 1,
        "languageLevelId": 2
    },
    {
        "languageId": 9,
        "languageLevelId": 3
    },
    {
        "languageId": 0,
        "languageLevelId": 3
    }
];
const LANGUAGE = {
    UKRAINIAN: 0,
    ENGLISH: 1,
    CHINESE: 2,
    SPANISH: 3,
    ARABIC: 4,
    JAPANESE: 5,
    HINDUSTANI: 6,
    FRENCH: 7,
    GERMAN: 8,
    RUSSIAN: 9,
    PORTUGUESE: 10,
    ITALIAN: 11
};

const LANGUAGE_LEVEL = {
    BEGINNER: 0,
    INTERMEDIATE: 1,
    ADVANCED: 2,
    NATIVE: 3
};

let meaningfulLanguages = [];

for (let language of languages) {
    let currentLanguage = null;
    let currentLevel = null;
    for (let l in LANGUAGE) {
        if (LANGUAGE[l] === language.languageId) currentLanguage = l;
    }
    for (let ll in LANGUAGE_LEVEL) {
        if (LANGUAGE_LEVEL[ll] === language.languageLevelId) currentLevel = ll;
    }
    meaningfulLanguages.push({language: currentLanguage, level: currentLevel});
}

console.log(meaningfulLanguages);
```